# Fetching individual value from an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter-3

Here I have two tables. Names are as follows: `rooms` and `student_hostel`.
The `rooms` table looks like this:

```
    id rm_number  capacity    bed_no               class    hostel  is_vaccant
    40    1         5       1A,1B,1C,1D,1E          27        7     1
    41    2         4       2A,2B,2C,2D             28        7     0
    42    3         3       3A,3B,3C                29        10    1
    43    4         4       4A,4B,4C,4D             30        10    1
    44    5         6       5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F       27        7     1
    45    6         7       6A,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G    29        10    1
```

The `student_hostel` table look like this:

```
     id     first_name     stud_id    hostel   class    room    bed     status
    175     siraj         WPGH00175     7      28        41      2A     P
    176     nesru         WPGH00176     7      28        41      2B     P
    177     faizal        WPGH00177     7      28        41      2C     P
    179     mashoor       WPGH00179     7      28        41      2D     G
    180     dsf           WPGH00180     7      27        40      1A     G
    181     ee            WPGH00181     7      27        40      1B     P
```

Here I want to get all status 'P' as in one color and all status 'G' in one color.
When I use my code like this:

Model:

```
public function view_room_status($num,$offset)
{   
        $this->db->select('rooms.*,class.name as class_name,hostel.name as hostel_name,student_hostel.status,student_hostel.id as s_id');
        $this->db->join('class','class.id=rooms.class');
        $this->db->join('hostel','hostel.id=rooms.hostel');
        $this->db->join('student_hostel','rooms.id=student_hostel.room','left');
        $this->db->group_by('rooms.id');
        $query=$this->db->get('rooms',$num,$offset)->result();
        return $query;
}
```

View looks like this:

```
     <tbody>
                <?php $n=1; 
                foreach($result as $row){ 
                  $tagsArray = explode(',', $row->bed_no);
                  $tagsLinksArray = array();?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $n++; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->rm_number)?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->class_name)?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->hostel_name)?></td>
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                      foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {

                        if($row->status=='P')
                        {
    // Remove spaces
                        $tagName = trim($tag);
                        $tagsLinksArray[]= '<a class="label label-success" href="view_room_occupied/'.$tagName.'">'.$tagName.'</a>';


                       }
                       elseif($row->status=='G')
                        {
    // Remove spaces
                        $tagName = trim($tag);
                        $tagsLinksArray[]= '<a class="label label-primary" href="view_room_occupied/'.$tagName.'">'.$tagName.'</a>';


                       }

                     }

// Join links in a string
                     $tagsLinks = implode(',', $tagsLinksArray);

                     echo $tagsLinks;?>

                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php } ?>
               </tbody>
```

The result I'm getting is all values in the array are becoming one color even if there is another status. Like this:

```
   sl no   room    class         hostel             Bed
     1       1     Periyar1     Periyar         1A,1B,1C,1D,1E
     2       2     Periyar2     Periyar         2A,2B,2C,2D
     3       3     Pamba1       Pamba       
     4       4     Pamba2       Pamba       
     5       5     Periyar1     Periyar     
     6       6     Pamba1       Pamba
```

Here '1A' status is 'P' and '1B' status' are 'G' but all '1A,1B.1C,1D,1E' are showing same color and like in second column '2A,2B,2C' status are 'P' and '2D' status is 'G' but getting same color for all. The result I want to get is '2A,2B,2C' should be one color because of the status 'P' and '2D' should be another color where status is 'G'.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are trying to get them in different colors??

Comment: color is just an assume.for status P i had given class as 'label label-success' and for status G i had given 'label label-primary',but the entire row is becoming the first one selected, whether its 'label label-success' or 'label label-primary'

Comment: With the way your tables are structured, joining on the room status is pointless. What you'll have to do after getting your initial result is to examine  each bed string by exploding it and comparing it against another query from your student_hostel table to get each rooms status and rebuild the Bed string wrapped in the appropriate CSS spans to give you your colors.

Comment: thanks for the information